# Error in implementing chart.js in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material, chart.js

I followed steps given in the link [Angular chart JS](http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/)
But unable to draw a graph(Bar graph) from the data.

My **dashboard.html** is

```
<div class="md-padding" flex layout-sm="column" >
<md-card class="text-center">
<md-card-content>
<canvas id="bar" class="chart chart-bar" ng-controller="DashboardCtrl"chart-data="data" chart-labels="labels" chart-series="series">
</canvas>
</md-card-content>
</md-card>
</div>
```

My **dashboardctrl.js** is

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular.module("home", ["chart.js"])
.config(['ChartJsProvider', function (ChartJsProvider) {
 ChartJsProvider.setOptions({
  chartColors: ['#FF5252', '#FF8A80'],
  responsive: false
  });
// Configure all line charts
ChartJsProvider.setOptions('line', {
  datasetFill: false
 });
}])
.controller("DashboardCtrl", ['$scope', function ($scope) {

$scope.labels = ['2006', '2007', '2008', '2009', '2010', '2011', '2012'];
$scope.series = ['Series A', 'Series B'];

$scope.data = [
  [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40],
  [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90]
];
console.log("done");
}]);
})();
```

I am getting **error**

> Multiple directives [ngController, chartBar] asking for new/isolated       scope on:`

Thanks for your help in advance.
`

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="md-padding" flex layout-sm="column" ng-controller="DashboardCtrl">
   <md-card class="text-center">
      <md-card-content>
         <canvas id="bar" class="chart chart-bar" chart-data="data" chart-labels="labels" chart-series="series"></canvas>
      </md-card-content>
   </md-card>
</div>
```

You need to move `ng-controller` to another element. Both the controller and the chartBar directive try to register a new isolated scope as the error message says

Comment: Sorry I'm getting empty div

Comment: create a fiddle please. Can't remote debug your code

Comment: And I gave you the solution